# Can we use an array to store static methods in PHP5 like C++11?

Tags: php

I'm trying to put some static methods into an array in PHP5. I wrote the following codes:

```
<?php
class A{
    public static func(){
        echo "A::func";
    }
}

$list_of_methods = array(
    A::func
);
```

However, it didn't work. My PHP told me that

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'A::func' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 3
```

In C++11, we can put a static method in a vector like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Test{
public:
        static void func(){
                cout<<"Test::func()"<<endl;
        }
};

int main(){
        vector<void(*)()>list_of_methods;
        list_of_methods.push_back(Test::func);
        list_of_methods[0]();
        return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering if there's any implementation like C++11 in PHP5?

It OK to use PHP7 too.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to do that, because it I get a feeling, that you are attempting to hack your way around a different issue. Something along the lines of [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @tereško What I want is use an array to stores `getInstance()` of different classes. So that I can write `vehicles['Car'](); vehicles['Bus']()` to get Car and Bus instance. And I want to use this mechanism for other operations.

Comment: That's a terrible approach. Instead you should use dependency injection.

Comment: Why don't you use `$class_name = 'Car'; new $class_name();` ,  define a class `Vehicle` and extend it to `Car` and `Bus`? You can even declare interfaces and traits. You are trying to break OOP style.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Actually `Car` and `Bus` extends `Vehicle`. And what I really want to do is to put `getInstance()` of all classes inherit from `Vehicle` into a list automatically. So that when I need `Car`, I just do something like I've talked above. And I've done a preprocessor that can find out all the classes inherit from `Vehicle`. The last step is to put them into the array. After editing/adding classes extends Vehicle, run the preprocessor, and it will add it to the array.

Comment: @ZhipengYANG please watch this lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0

Comment: If you need an instance of `Car` you just write `new Car()` or dynamically `new $class_name()`. So you haven't clarified why you believe to need such a strange way.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone what you are telling him to do is not much better, without a proper context.

Answer (score 1):

Callables in PHP can be static methods. It's basically just an array of strings:

```
Test::func();

// can also be written as:
call_user_func(array('Test', 'func'));
```

So in your case, you'd have:

```
$list_of_methods = array(
    array('A' ,'func')
);

call_user_func($list_of_methods[0]);
```

For non-static methods, the first item should not be a string of the class name, but the object itself:

```
$test = new Test();
$test->func();

// can also be written as:
$test = new Test();
call_user_func(array($test, 'func'));
```

Check out [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for more information about callables in PHP.

Comment: Statiс function can be called directly `$list_of_methods[0]();`